# how to get KeycloakSession in embedded keycloak with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm working on a project that runs embedded keycloak in the spring boot application (based on this article: https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app). I want to access KeycloakSession for some usages, for example in UserResource is a class that provides rest API to get user information by username I do this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserResource {

 private final KeycloakSession session;

 @Bean
 public KeycloakSession keycloakSession() {
     return new DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory().create();
 }
 
 @GetMapping("{username}")
 public Response getUserInfo(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
     RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
     UserModel user = session.users().getUserByUsername(username, realm);

     // codes removed for brevity
 }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the above rest, the session object and its fields are null, so I get null pointer exception. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you're trying to do something entirely inadvisable. From that blog post you linked, the purpose is to set-up a "Keycloak server embedded in a Spring Boot application. _This makes it easy to start up a pre-configured Keycloak server._" The purpose of that blog post is just to run Keycloak, not to integrate it with your custom REST API.

Comment: After this problem, I faced with other problems. Then, by contacting the community and people who are working with Keycloak, I found out that this is a bad way to integrate Keycloak with Spring Boot. Because, a lot of features aren't supported in this way, and also if one wants to add a new feature to Keycloak, one can't find any way in upstream projects and documents. So, I setback from this way.

Answer (score 2):

I have quite a different way of doing things: I don't mix resource and authorization servers: I try to avoid coupling as much as possible, and I just like the idea of SSO (the same authorization server shared by several apps).

I write Keycloak mappers to enrich access and ID tokens (you can find such a mapper using Keycloak user session [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper)) and resource servers using those "rich" JWTs issued by Keycloak [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/user-proxies-api).

Both links above are from a complete project with [READMEs to get you started](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies):

- Angular UI (with Ionic for building both web and mobile native apps)
- REST API with Spring resource-servers
- Keycloak as authorization-server

There are 2 different clients for resource and authorization servers:

- Keycloak mapper (using client credentials flow)
- Ionic app (using authorization code + PKCSE)

##### P.S.

The architecture of this project is deprecated: the Angular app shouldn't be an OAuth2 client. It's requests should be authorized with sessions (and CSRF protection) on a BFF (for instance `spring-cloud-gateway` so that:

- the OAuth2 client could be confidential (only clients on a server can keep a secret)
- tokens are hidden from remote devices and the code running on it

But this wouldn't change how the tokens are enriched and the data used on resource servers behind the BFF.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late, and I hope you've already found a solution. However, I'm providing an answer for the next person who comes across this issue.

I needed to fetch a Keycloak session in an extra event listener and modify a user's attribute. To achieve this, I used the following code:

```
    val factory: KeycloakSessionFactory = KeycloakApplication.getSessionFactory()
    this.kcSession = factory.create()
    kcSession!!.transactionManager.begin()
    this.realm = kcSession!!.realms().getRealm("sample")

    logger.info("==========================================================================")
    logger.info("Incoming new event: $event")
    logger.info("==========================================================================")
    with(event) {
        val user = kcSession!!.users().getUserById(userId, realm) ?: throw Exception(Error.UserNotFound)
        user.setSingleAttribute("firstName", name)
    }

    kcSession!!.transactionManager.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The session object won't be set in your UserResource, but with embedded KeyCloak, you can get it in EmbeddedKeycloakRequestFilter:

```
public class EmbeddedKeycloakRequestFilter extends AbstractRequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        ClientConnection clientConnection = createConnection((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

        filter(clientConnection, (session) -> {
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

                RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();

                System.out.println(realm.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private ClientConnection createConnection(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ClientConnection() {
            @Override
            public String getRemoteAddr() {
                return request.getRemoteAddr();
            }

            @Override
            public String getRemoteHost() {
                return request.getRemoteHost();
            }

            @Override
            public int getRemotePort() {
                return request.getRemotePort();
            }

            @Override
            public String getLocalAddr() {
                return request.getLocalAddr();
            }

            @Override
            public int getLocalPort() {
                return request.getLocalPort();
            }
        };
    }
}
```